# Is possible to delete a bad reference on a LinkedIn profile?

Tags: linkedin

I would like to know if it's easy to delete a bad reference from a profile.

Or do I need to report it?

Answer (score 3):

If you have [written a recommendation, you can delete it](https://help.linkedin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/48). But if you have accepted a recommendation, there is no option to delete it but you can hide it from your your profile.

From [Help Center](https://help.linkedin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/165/~/hiding-and-unhiding-your-recommendations):

> Hide or display a recommendation that you previously accepted
>
> 1. Go to your profile.
> 2. Scroll to the **Recommendations** section and click **Manage**.
> 3. Scroll to the recommendation you want to hide or display.
> 4. Check the box to display it on your profile or **uncheck the box to hide it**.

If you hide a received recommendation, it will also be hidden from the profile of the person who gave it to you.

Comment: ok, so if I hide it, it won't be visible anymore (neither on my on his profile), so basically as if it has been deleted. Correct?

Comment: No, it will not delete..it will be hidden from your profile and will be visible only to you. Anytime you can unhide it.